# Random sampling of n lists of m elements in python

Tags: python, random, permutation, combinatorics, sampling

I wrote this code which creates all combinations of n lists of m elements in python, samples a given number of unique combinations (max possible or 1000) and outputs it in excel. It basically works, but the problem is that when product(m_i) becomes very large, it is extremely slow.

A realistic use case could be that I have 32 lists with each 2-3 elements in each, from which I would need to sample 1000 unique combinations. That could be 10 billion combinations, but it is slow to create all these combinations, when I actually only need 1000 unique combinations.

I did consider just creating random samples and checking whether I already created this one, but that would become slow when numbers of samples approach number of possible permutations.

[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpnx6.png)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Variables.xlsx',sheet_name="Variables" ,index_col=0)
df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.index)

df.shape[0]
def for_recursive(number_of_loops, range_list, execute_function, current_index=0, iter_list = []):
    if iter_list == []:
        iter_list = [0]*number_of_loops
    
    if current_index == number_of_loops-1:
        for iter_list[current_index] in range_list.iloc[current_index].dropna():
            execute_function(iter_list)
    else:
        for iter_list[current_index] in range_list.iloc[current_index].dropna():
            for_recursive(number_of_loops, iter_list = iter_list, range_list = range_list,  current_index = current_index+1, execute_function = execute_function) 
            
def do_whatever(index_list):
    df_out.loc[len(df_out)] = index_list
    
for_recursive(range_list = df, execute_function = do_whatever , number_of_loops=len(df))

df_out = df_out.sample(n=min(len(df_out),1000))

with pd.ExcelWriter("Variables.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
    df_out.to_excel(writer, 'Simulations', index=False)
```

Comment: i am seeing red flags. [1] `for loops` mixed with dataframes = slow, [2] reading & writing to excel files = slow.

Comment: for loops and dataframes (watch this):  https://youtu.be/0EkFJNTOs7E . . .  classical error.

Comment: Are you ever going to want to select anything close to the full set?

Comment: Bah, this sounded interesting until you brought excel/pandas into it. Not gonna spend time on this then. Are they really necessary for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the standard library functionality. The `itertools` module can generate the list of all possible combinations in the data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],  
                    'B': [1, 4, 6, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    'C': [2, 6, 8, 44, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    'D': [3, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    })

from itertools import product 

full_collection = (list(product(data['A'], data['B'], data['C'], data['D'])))

print(len(full_collection)) # 10000
```

The `random.sample` function will generate unique samples without repetition.

```
import random

samples = random.sample(full_collection, 1000)
```

**EDIT: A possible alternative solution**

Instead of creating the list of all possible combinations, generate random combinations from the unique values in each of the dataset columns. The generator expression ensures a memory efficient solution, however it does not guarantee that each sample will be unique.

```
sample_size = 1000

# Get the column names
col_names = tuple(data.columns)

# Create a dictionary of unique values in each column
unique_values = dict()
for col_name in col_names:
    unique_values[col_name] = tuple(data[col_name].unique())

# Create a sample generator
samples_gen = (tuple([random.choice(unique_values[col_name]) 
                      for col_name in col_names]) 
               for _ in range(sample_size))

# Iterate through the generated samples
while True:
    try:
        sample = next(samples_gen)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # Do something with the sample
    print(sample)
```

Using a closure function to create a simpler iterator:

```
def sample_generator_from_dataframe(data, col_names=None):
    if col_names is None:
        col_names = tuple(data.columns)
    unique_values = dict()
    for col_name in col_names:
        unique_values[col_name] = tuple(data[col_name].unique())

    # An infinite sample generator
    def _generator():
        while True:
            yield tuple([random.choice(unique_values[col_name]) 
                        for col_name in col_names])

    return iter(_generator)


# Initialise the generator with the dataframe content
new_sample_gen = sample_generator_from_dataframe(data)

# Iterate over generated samples
for _ in range(sample_size):
    sample = next(new_sample_gen)
    # Do something with the generated sample
    print(sample)
```

Comment: That is a lot better than what I made :) It does however still get slow when I start having a lot of parameters in the dataset (e.g. A through T instead of only A through D). Would it be possible to not create the full collection, but only create a random fraction?

Comment: You could generate samples from the unique values in each column. I've updated the answer with code for such a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't select anything approaching the number of possibilities, then this seems relatively quick.

```
import string
import random

## ------------------
## create a bunch of short lists
## ------------------
data = [random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 3) for _ in range(32)]
## ------------------

## ------------------
## out of the trillions of possibilities, select n.
## n should not approach the number of possibilities
## ------------------
n = 1000
results = set()
while len(results) <= n:
    results.add(tuple(random.choice(row) for row in data))
## ------------------

for row in results:
    print("".join(row))
```